# How to restrict the outbound traffic of user's pods in Kubernetes?

Tags: networking, kubernetes, iptables, policy

Now we're using `Kubernetes` to implement the PaaS service and users can ssh into the containers. Because container runs inside the network of Kubernetes, users can access the services like `kube-apiserver`.

We want to restrict the outbound of the user's pods. It seems that `Kubernetes Network Policy` is only for inbound traffic now.

Is that possible to do that? Should we setup the rules of `iptables` in compute nodes?

Comment: Sure, you must do iptables rules on the nodes according what you need!

Comment: did you find any solution for that?

Answer (score 2):

Outbound traffic is now supported by Network Policies since v1.8, you should check again and see if your use case is fully supported.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#default-deny-all-egress-traffic